# Javascript Files 404 error after loading my website on google search console

Tags: javascript, github-pages, google-search-console

I created a website for an important exam that I will have to take in a few days. I hosted the site with github Pages and everything worked perfectly. Since I uploaded the site to Google Search Console, however, the site shows a 404 error for all Javascript files. It's already been 3 days since the site uploaded to the google console.

Here is the link of my site: https://manux895.github.io/EsameDiStato

Comment: [Something in my website or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) -> TLDR: No

Comment: I know the rules well here. There is no code to check and test. I've provided the link just to show the error I'm having, however this isn't critical to the question